# 2005-2010s animated TV show featuring different colored monkeys with super powers

Tags: story-identification, tv, animation

I remember watching a kids' science fiction show on Cartoon Network around 2010-2013 in India, though it looked like a show from early 2000s. The show had different colored monkeys with super powers (there were 5-6 monkeys) and I remember one of them being old and black, who looked like the head of their group. They also had a giant robot which helped them in fights sometimes. I also remember that the show would get a little dark sometimes, with the black monkey having a secret.
Any help in identifying this show would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***[Super Robot Monkey Team Hyperforce Go!](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0423746/)*** (2004–2006)...?

From IMDB:

> A twelve-year-old boy named Chiro was exploring the outskirts of Shuggazoom City and discovered a giant and abandoned Super Robot.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Robot_Monkey_Team_Hyperforce_Go!):

> *Super Robot Monkey Team Hyperforce Go!* (commonly known by its acronym, *SRMTHFG*) is an anime-influenced television series created by Ciro Nieli, one of the directors of *Teen Titans*, and produced by Jetix Animation Concepts with animation being done by The Answer Studio (who would later work on the Cartoon Network series *Transformers: Animated*). It was the first original show produced for the Jetix block and for the Jetix channels worldwide, where the show premiered on September 18, 2004.
>
> Set mainly on the fictional planet of Shuggazoom, the series follows the adventures of five cyborg monkeys and a human boy named Chiro as they struggle to protect their planet – and the rest of the universe – from the forces of evil.

Comment: thanks dude, just what i was talking about